# How to install the application on a Garmin watch?

Tags: garmin

I developed the application, but did not find a way to install it in my watch, bypassing the garmin application store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I connected the clock to the computer, copied the .prg file to the /app directory and the application appeared in the clock.